# Salesforce flow Datatable multiple resource

Tags: datatable, salesforce, salesforce-flow

In my flow I am getting accounts filtered with Billing city with get records. I have two get records elements to filter data on two different cities. I want to show selected rows from both the tables in third table. I tried Assignment element and formula element but both are not available for datatable resources.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both lists of different getRecord elements are from the same object, then you can use an Assignment element to add each list to a collection of variables